# New to python. How do you Print() and indent and space without it giving a error?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and need help because I have no clue how to space in a print()
lemme show you what I'm working on

```
#Receipt.py


#Create a program that will prompt the user for an item description, the price of the item, and the quantity purchased. 
#The program will output the final cost including all taxes. Your output should look as follows...
#
#Sample Output
#Enter the description: Volleyball
#Enter the price: 39.99
#Enter the quantity: 4

#RECEIPT
#-------------------------------------------------
#Description   QTY      price       Subtotal
#Volleyball      4           $39.99    $159.96

#HST:                                             $20.79
#-------------------------------------------------
#Total:                                          $180.75

#user inputs 
def main():
    print("Welcome!")
    Description = input("What is the name of the item?")
    Price = float(input("What is the price?"))
    Quantity = float(input("What is the quantity of the item?"))

    #variables 
    Tax = 1.13

    #boring math 
    Total = Price * Quantity * Tax

    #what the user has inputted

    print( "You have inputted the following")
    print("The item is", Description)
    print("The price is", Price)
    print("The Quantity is", Quantity)

    #Asking the user if it is correct
    Answer = int(input("Is this want you want? If \"no\" type 1 if \"yes\" type 2")
    if Answer = "1":
        main()
#ignore the top part lol thaz extra 
 else:
    print("Receipt")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print (Description     Price     Subtotal)
```

tldr

```
As you can see I'm trying to make it like this 
Sample Output
Enter the description: Volleyball
Enter the price: 39.99
Enter the quantity: 4
RECEIPT
-------------------------------------------------
Description   QTY      price       Subtotal
Volleyball      4           $39.99    $159.96
HST:                                             $20.79
-------------------------------------------------
Total:                                          $180.75
```

but every time I try it gives me a error
Please use simple things cause I'm just a beginner and don't be to harsh on me lol 
If you have any tips list them down below!
Thanks :)

Comment: What error do you get? Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be from this line, `print (Description     Price     Subtotal)`, 
you have to separate out arguments to the print function with a `,`, so 
`print (Description,     Price,     Subtotal)` should work. Also please try to include the interpreter outputs when posting errors as they are helpful for debugging. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: https://gyazo.com/434c12af13d2cf730553305359be529c it doesn't line up is there any way to do so. I have no clue if my teacher wants it like that

Comment: The print statement does not take whitespace into account. If you want it to line up, you'll have to use format strings or something similar, eg `print(f"{Description}  {Price}  {Subtotal}")`. You can refer to the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Your have syntax issues on your print statements. Please check the syntax for printing variables. Also variables need to be separated using commas.

Comment: the problem is that it dosent line up is there a way to do so in python? gyazo.com/434c12af13d2cf730553305359be529c

Answer (score 0):

Check out string formatting for Python.

```
Description = "Volleyball"
Quantity = 4
Price = 39.99
Subtotal = 159.96
name = "bug_spray"

# For newer versions of Python (>=3.6)
# Use f-strings
print(f"{Description}   {Quantity}   {Price:.2f}   {Subtotal:.2f}")
print(f"Hi {name}")

# For older versions of Python
# Use modulo operator
print("%s   %d    %.2f    %.2f" % (Description, Quantity, Price, Subtotal))
print("Hi %s" % name)

# Or use .format() (for Python >= 2.6)
print("{0}   {1}    {2}    {3}".format(Description, Quantity, Price, Subtotal))
print("Hi {0}".format(name))
```

Also careful of how you indent stuff with if-else statements.

*EDIT*: I also a syntax error where you wrote `if Answer = "1"`. It should instead look like:

```
if (Answer == 1):
    ...
else:
    ...
```